# C# Downcasting Lists to IList "special tactics"

Tags: c#

So I'm working at a company and I'm relatively new here but I've come across something very strange in some production code which I'm told are written by someone much more knowledgable in C# than myself who "does things a special way".  So I'm trying to think of reasons to do what I'm about to explain, giving the benefit of the doubt but I can't come up with anything.

`IList<Facility> Facilities = new List<Facility>();`

The above line is at the core of the problem... the other oddities all throughout the code come from being unable to use interfaces for some things and therefore the data has to be copied back out into a List before using them (for example exporting via webservice, does not allow using an interface, must be an implementation of IList)

Now I understand interfaces are wonderful in the sense that you can write methods which expect the methods presribed in the interface to exist on the implementation which is being passed to your method but...

Can someone please help me out here...  can anyone think of a reason you'd immediately downcast a List back to its interface in the data layer of an application?

Also just to make it clear...  these lists are not used for interchangeable data types either, this occurs at the point where the List is defined and stored, and there is an IList per datatype which is stored.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is considered good practice to work with the highest possible class in the hierarchy. So if you only need to loop through the values you should only expose `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
IEnumerable<Facility> Facilities = new List<Facility>();
// now you can foreach over the facilities or chain with LINQ
```

If you need indexer access you could use `IList<Facility>`

```
IList<Facility> Facilities = new List<Facility>();
// in addition to looping now you can access facilities by index 
// and you can also add and remove facilities
```

The idea behind exposing the highest possible class/interface in the hierarchy when designing some API is that this way you are hiding the implementation details that you are using a `List<T>`. If you tomorrow you invent a `HyperSpecialListWhichIsVeryFast<T>` which implements the contract that you agreed upon with the consumer of the API, this consumer doesn't need to change anything in his code. He doesn't care. He works with `IEnumerable<T>` because all he needs is to loop for example. And thanks to your new list his code will run faster without him needing to change anything.

But using a non-generic à la .NET 1.0 weakly typed collections which are in the history books now is like voodoo magic:

```
IList Facilities = new List<Facility>();
```

Cannot think of any reason why this would be useful. Downcasting to a non-generic version will force the client to cast in order to access the underlying type `T`. This way he is loosing all the compile-time safety that generics provide.

Comment: The weird thing there is that they are downcasting to IList and not IList<Facility>();

Comment: agreed! I would also always use the templated version and not the generic one!

Comment: @ivowiblo, yes, that's the weird thing. Can't think of a good reason why one would do this.

Comment: Like @Darin said if a method returns IEnumerable<> then any class implementing this interface can consume the result.

Comment: Well, my answer is "doesn't make any sense to downcasting to a non-generic type, unless you are exposing it in a specific interface, or abstract or virtual method implementation"

Comment: As noted, the point is encapsulation. The consumer shouldn't know what the underlying implementation is. Why they created a `List<T>` and then upcast it to a non-generic `IList` (rather than `IList<T>` is a mystery. I suspect that the reason is historical: the code likely predates generics. Somebody decided to use generics...and then realized that the consumer end of things used the old stuff. That's my suspicion, anyways. Or perhaps, you've got .Net 1.1 assemblies using this that don't support generics.

Comment: @NicholasCarey, this can't be a .NET 1.1 assembly as it uses a generic `List<T>`. Neither the consumer can be. This code is in an assembly which is at least .NET 2.0.

Comment: Wait this is my bad, the IList do define the type, I've updated the question sorry

Comment: Also... this isn't for an API... this is in the consumer code

Comment: Original response is good but I'm still not certain about it... it makes sense to cast to the interface in a method which is designed to work with different Lists...  but my question is, why would you store the data in this way

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Right...but there might be a 1.1 assembly in the mix somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about how you intend to consume your `Facilities` variable.  If you only intend to opearte on it as an `IList` (you only intend to invoke method on it as defined in that interface) it is reasonable to declare the variable as such to enforce a constraint that you don't attempt to invoke methods that are *not* defined on that interface.  This way, you can easily substitute out the data structure you use to another implementation of `IList`.

Myself, I typically avoid using the non-generic version unless I have a specific need. (i.e. I would use `IList<Facility>` instead of `IList`)   One possible scenario for using the non-generic version (in other places in your code) is that it obviously doesn't demand that other code know anything about `Facility` -- it can operate on the list as a general list of objects.

Comment: IMHO, it's too bad `IList<T>` doesn't inherit non-generic`IList`; it could do so safely if the non-generic version were a read-only implementation, and doing so would make it possible for code which accepts an `IEnumerable<Animal>` to access the `Count` property of a passed-in `IList<Zebra>`.

Comment: This is the problem...  everything is stored as IList<T> but then in other places in the code where it's used for example to export on a webservice, the data is copied out of the IList<T> back into a List<T>

Answer (score 0):

If one has an interface which includes all the members of a class that one needs, there isn't much disadvantage to using the interface everyplace one would use the class, with the sole exception of constructor calls and static methods (where one must use the class(*)).  The biggest problem with using the interface instead of the class is also the biggest reason for doing it: code which specifies the interface will often be interface awkwardly with code that uses the class; if there's any possibility that it might in future be necessary to use the interface, doing so from the get-go can avoid a potentially-awkward refactoring job later.

(*)If I had my druthers, an interface could specify a class to use for constructors or static methods, such that if a declaration interface IFoo specified it was 'partnered' with Foo, then `IFoo.Bar()` would be equivalent to `Foo.Bar()`, and `new IFoo(3)` would be equivalent to `new Foo(3)`'.  Unfortunately, no such feature exists; if it did, I suspect interfaces would get used much more consistently.